# how to capture non-event-driven data in keen-io

Tags: business-intelligence, keen-io, data-collection

Capturing data in Keen.io is pretty straight-forward when it's driven by an event. (User-logged-in, Customer-bought-stuff, ...). That's very nicely explained in the docs.

But what is the best approach when I want insight on a state of my app at a given time in the past?

For instance: how many active licenses were there this time last year?

Our first thought is to run a cronjob every hour, to get those data from te DB, and store them in a custom collection. Is this the right approach, or are there better solutions?